# Designing an active bandpass filter and selecting R and C values

Tags: circuit-design, filter, band-pass

I have been assigned the task to design an active bandpass filter with a passband of 0.1 to 10 Hz. At these two frequencies, there should be an attenuation of -6dB or more. So far I have selected my circuit layout which can be seen below:

[image]

I then found my transfer function so that I could calculate the R and C values but I was running into issues with solving bc of the imaginary numbers.
[image]

I tried putting using the standard bandpass transfer function to solve for Q and then use that to solve for R and C but I was running into the same issue of always having a j in the final value.

[image]

I tried solving for Q through a Python program but was getting these crazy values.

[image]

Comment: I didn't see a question; just that you couldn't achieve this or that. Can you ask an actual question please?

Answer (score 2):

Since low frequency is much smaller than high frequency (2 decades) you can design the band pass filter like a combination of high pass + low pass.

See https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/filter/filter_7.html

Chapter "Inverting Band Pass Filter Circuit".

The transfer function is :
$$
H(s)=\frac{-R_2}{R_1}\frac{sR_1C_1}{1+sR_1C_1}\frac{1}{1+sR_2C_2}
$$

To find exact corner frequencies (from math point of view) you have to follow Jan Eerland method.

But you can see that transfer function have 1st order low pass + high pass and you can treat them separately if flp >> fhp. For example we made the assumption that R1C1 = 100*R2C2 (set also gain of 1). At frequency of w=1/R1C1 we have

$$
|H(\frac{j}{R_1C_1})|=\frac{1}{1+1}\frac{1}{1+1/100} \approx \frac{1}{2}
$$

Low pass term are neglectable. Then when w=1/R2C2

$$
|H(\frac{j}{R_2C_2})|=\frac{100}{1+100}\frac{1}{1+1} \approx \frac{1}{2}
$$

High pass term are neglectable.

However in this example corner frequency formula are for 3dB bandwidth. For 6dB you need to re-compute them. I got this :

$$
\omega_{hp}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}R_1C_1},\omega_{lp}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{R_2C_2} 
$$

Quick check with R1=R2=100k :

[image]

High pass corner frequency (6dB):
$$|H(j\omega_{hp})|=\frac{1}{2}=\frac{|j\omega_{hp} R_1 C_1|}{|1+j\omega_{hp} R_1 C_1|} = 
\frac{\omega_{hp} R_1 C_1}{\sqrt{1+(\omega_{hp} R_1 C_1)^2}}
$$
$$ 
\frac{1}{4}= \frac{(\omega_{hp} R_1 C_1)^2}{1+(\omega_{hp} R_1 C_1)^2}\\
1+(\omega_{hp} R_1 C_1)^2=4(\omega_{hp} R_1 C_1)^2 \\
1=3(\omega_{hp} R_1 C_1)^2 \\
\frac{1}{3} = (\omega_{hp} R_1 C_1)^2 \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} = \omega_{hp} R_1 C_1 \\
\omega_{hp} =  \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}R_1 C_1} 
$$

For low pass corner frequency (6dB) :
$$|H(j\omega_{lp})|=\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{|1+j\omega_{lp} R_2 C_2|} = 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+(\omega_{lp} R_2 C_2)^2}}
$$
$$ 
\frac{1}{4}= \frac{1}{1+(\omega_{lp} R_2 C_2)^2}\\
1+(\omega_{lp} R_2 C_2)^2=4\\
(\omega_{lp} R_2 C_2)^2=3 \\
\omega_{lp} R_2 C_2=\sqrt3 \\
\omega_{lp} =\frac{\sqrt3 }{R_2 C_2}
$$

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. Can you please explain how you recomputed the corner frequency equations?

Comment: Any help would be greatly appreciated here. Your answer makes the most sense to me but I am lost on how the corner frequency equations were remodeled.

Comment: Simply solving |H(jw)|=1/2 (6dB) instead of 1/sqrt(2) (3dB). Please find the detail in the edited answer.

Comment: Thanks. I am following the math you did now, however, I am still confused about where the equations you used came from. Why are you only using a partial version of the transfer function for the low and high pass corner frequencies and why are both of them different?

Comment: So I did a VCL at Vx (node in between R1 and C1) and I got your high pass equation. Still not sure how you got the low pass equation. Just wanted to say your component values from above are working so thank you for that.

Comment: Ok so I see now that your equations are just the default transfer functions for a first order low pass and high pass filter. I am not sure how to calculate the low pass transfer function though like I did for the high pass with KCL since R2 and C2 are in parallel.

Comment: Equation come from single pole active high pass filter (C2 = open circuit) and single pole active low pass filter (C1 = short circuit). See https://www.analog.com/en/education/education-library/linear-circuit-design-handbook.html Chapter 8 : Analog Filters, page 8.88.

Comment: There is probably a way to derive this by simplifying the transfer function when C2R2 << C1R1 but I can't remember how. I 'have seen this long time ago at school...

Answer (score 1):

Well, [notice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier#Inverting_amplifier) that we have the following transfer function:

$$\mathscr{H}\left(\text{s}\right):=\frac{\text{V}_\text{o}\left(\text{s}\right)}{\text{V}_\text{i}\left(\text{s}\right)}=-\frac{\displaystyle\frac{1}{\text{sC}_2}\space\text{||}\space\text{R}_2}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1+\frac{1}{\text{sC}_1}}=-\frac{\text{C}_1\text{R}_2\text{s}}{\left(1+\text{C}_1\text{R}_1\text{s}\right)\left(1+\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\text{s}\right)}\tag1$$

Where \$\alpha\space\text{||}\space\beta:=\frac{\alpha\beta}{\alpha+\beta}\$.

So, we get:

$$\left|\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|=\frac{\text{C}_1\text{R}_2\omega}{\sqrt{1+\left(\text{C}_1\text{R}_1\omega\right)^2}\cdot\sqrt{1+\left(\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\omega\right)^2}}\tag2$$

Solving for the maximum gives:

$$\frac{\partial\left|\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|}{\partial\omega}=0\space\Longrightarrow\space\omega:=\hat{\omega}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_1\text{R}_2}}\tag3$$

So, we get:

$$\left|\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\hat{\omega}\right)\right|=\frac{\text{C}_1\text{R}_2}{\text{C}_1\text{R}_1+\text{C}_2\text{R}_2}\tag4$$

Solving for the passband we get:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\frac{\text{C}_1\text{R}_2}{\text{C}_1\text{R}_1+\text{C}_2\text{R}_2}=\left|\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|\space\Longrightarrow\space$$
$$\omega:=\omega_\pm=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\left(\text{C}_1\text{R}_1\right)^2+\left(\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\right)^2+6\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_1\text{R}_2}\pm\left(\text{C}_1\text{R}_1+\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\right)}\tag5$$

Using [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/592998/how-is-the-slope-of-the-frequency-response-of-an-analog-active-filter-defined/593007#593007) answer, we can see that we have attenuation of:

$$-20\space\text{dB/decade}\space\text{and}\space-20\log_{10}\left(2\right)\approx-6.0206\space\text{dB/octave}$$

Solving for \$\text{R}_1\$ and \$\text{R}_2\$ gives two possibilities:

$$\text{R}_1=\frac{99-\sqrt{9401}}{40\pi\text{C}_1}\space\text{and}\space\text{R}_2=\frac{99+\sqrt{9401}}{40\pi\text{C}_2}\tag6$$
$$\text{R}_1=\frac{99+\sqrt{9401}}{40\pi\text{C}_1}\space\text{and}\space\text{R}_2=\frac{99-\sqrt{9401}}{40\pi\text{C}_2}\tag7$$

I used the following Mathematica code:

```
In[1]:=Clear["Global`*"];
s = I*\[Omega];
h = -((((1/(s*C2))*(R2))/((1/(s*C2)) + (R2)))/(R1 + (1/(s*C1))));
H = FullSimplify[
   Sqrt[ComplexExpand[Re[h]]^2 + ComplexExpand[Im[h]]^2], 
   Assumptions -> \[Omega] >= 0 && C1 > 0 && C2 > 0 && R1 > 0 && 
     R2 > 0];
Subscript[\[Omega], max] = 
  FullSimplify[\[Omega] /. 
    Solve[{D[H, \[Omega]] == 0, \[Omega] > 0 && C1 > 0 && C2 > 0 && 
        R1 > 0 && R2 > 0}, \[Omega]][[1]], 
   Assumptions -> C1 > 0 && C2 > 0 && R1 > 0 && R2 > 0];
k = FullSimplify[
   Solve[{H == (1/Sqrt[2])*
       FullSimplify[(H /. \[Omega] -> Subscript[\[Omega], max]), 
        Assumptions -> 
         C1 > 0 && C2 > 0 && R1 > 0 && R2 > 0], \[Omega] > 0 && 
      C1 > 0 && C2 > 0 && R1 > 0 && R2 > 0}, \[Omega]], 
   Assumptions -> C1 > 0 && C2 > 0 && R1 > 0 && R2 > 0];
Subscript[\[Omega], 1] = 
  FullSimplify[\[Omega] /. k[[1]], 
   Assumptions -> C1 > 0 && C2 > 0 && R1 > 0 && R2 > 0];
Subscript[\[Omega], 2] = 
  FullSimplify[\[Omega] /. k[[2]], 
   Assumptions -> C1 > 0 && C2 > 0 && R1 > 0 && R2 > 0];
Subscript[f, 1] = 1/10;
Subscript[f, 2] = 10;
FullSimplify[
 Solve[{Subscript[\[Omega], 1] == 2*Pi*Subscript[f, 1], 
   Subscript[\[Omega], 2] == 2*Pi*Subscript[f, 2], 
   C1 > 0 && C2 > 0 && R1 > 0 && R2 > 0}, {R1, R2}], 
 Assumptions -> C1 > 0 && C2 > 0]

Out[1]={{R1 -> -((-99 + Sqrt[9401])/(40 C1 \[Pi])), 
  R2 -> (99 + Sqrt[9401])/(40 C2 \[Pi])}, {R1 -> (99 + Sqrt[9401])/(
   40 C1 \[Pi]), R2 -> -((-99 + Sqrt[9401])/(40 C2 \[Pi]))}}
```

Comment: Jan, thank you so much. I was following up until step 3. So you are basically taking the derivative with respect to , solving for , and then plugging that back into the original transfer function? Why can you not set  equal to the center frequency of sqrt(0.1*10) and then solve for 10^(-6/20) = ℋ(j) which your math showed how to get the imaginary numbers out.

Answer (score 1):

The boundaries of the band will be set by the resistors and their accompanying capacitors. Obviously, those can be extracted from the transfer function, as I can see the TF is shouting these boundaries out: Lower boundary is set by R1-C1 pair, and the higher boundary is set by R2-C2 pair.

But let's forget the calculations for a moment. Instead, approach to the problem from a practical point of view.

The mid-band (or pass-band) gain will be determined by R2 and R1 only:

$$
A_{Vm}=-\frac{R_2}{R_1}
$$

So you should know the mid-band gain first. `At these two frequencies, there should be an attenuation of -6dB or more.` This might be an indication of unity gain for pass-band. So R2 and R1 can be equal. But in any case, they are "tied" to each other.

Now, you can't pick random values for R1 and R2. Because:

- If you select very low resistances (e.g. less than 50R) then these resistors will load the signal source (That's a thing we almost always don't want to happen). For example, since the inverting input is kept at ground level by the negative feedback, the load impedance seen by the signal source will be the series-connected R1-C1 pair. And at high frequencies (e.g. >500 Hz) C1 will simply disappear so R1 will load the signal source. Be careful with the value you choose for R1 (and R2, of course). You may want to know the properties of the signal source (e.g. is it coming from a pre-amplifier? What's the driving impedance of the signal source?).
- Since the lower boundary is really low (0.1Hz) you'll end up with a high value for C1 (like hundreds or a few thousands of microfarads). You may want to increase R1 (and therefore R2) to decrease the capacitance but you can't go beyond some level for R1 (and R2) because the input bias currents will start to play a significant role on gain, and therefore the overall performance.

Select an operational amplifier based on your gain-bandwidth product (GBW) requirements first. I can see the bandwidth is about 10 Hz so any op amp should work here. But for the input bias current, if you select an op amp with bias currents in uA range then the resistors can't be higher than a few tens of kiloohms. This means that the C1 will be a few hundreds of microfarads.

The rest is simple.

**FINAL NOTE:** If there's no specific reason of choosing an "inverting" active band-pass filter, you can switch to a non-inverting one:

Comment: Hi Rohat, thank you for your response. Would I need to set the -R2/R1 formula equal to 0.5 which is the result of 10^(-6/20)? From there, how would I figure out what the C1 and C2 values need to be?

Comment: @palacetrading Check your requirements again. It states "-6dB of attenuation at boundaries i.e. cut-off frequencies". So no, you're not supposed to set the mid-band gain to 0.5. As I stated in my answer, once you get the ratio of the resistors, pick values for them (e.g. 20k each for unity mid-band gain) then check if the op amp's input bias current would bring a problem, considering the input voltage range (e.g. input bias current times R1 (or R2) will give you a drop which should be way lower than minimum input voltage). Then workout the transfer function.

Comment: Hi Rohat, I think I see what you are saying now but my mid-band gain is irrelevant. The only thing that matters is that I get -6db at the critical frequencies. I am still not sure what formula to use to calculate the component values at these frequencies with the required attenuation.